# can not access portal after specifying port in URL

Tags: amazon-ec2, port, django, url

Django webservices is running on port 8000 (pyhon manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000)

I am able to access using ,  https://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin/

but if I specify port in url, https://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/admin/
I am not able to access the portal..

What could be possible mistakes ?

Best Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reach port 8000 from outside AWS, you must add it as a permitted port in your AWS security group.

Comment: port 80, 443, 8000, 8001 all are all allowed in security group for my instance.setting 22 (SSH) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
8001 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
8002 0.0.0.0/0 Delete

Comment: is there any need of restart after adding new rule in security group settings or it gets effective on fly.

Answer (score 0):

The first link you provide is 'https://...', so this would be accessing port 443 of the server.  In order for this to work, there must be something (apache, nginx, pound, ...) proxying the requests through to the python process.  It probably also means that it's hosting an SSL cert.

The second link is 'https://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/admin/', so you're trying to talk SSL to a HTTP server.  You might try `http://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/admin/` - note it's HTTP not HTTPS.